# Конвертация векторной графики в растровую при создании swf-игры

Tags: flash, swf

Я сделал игру в Adobe Flash и экспортирую ее в swf. Все прекрасно работает, но векторная графика сильно тормозит игру, хотя никаких сложных действий я с ней не выполняю. В сцене > 100 объектов и вручную конвертировать их в растровые объекты не хочется.
Нельзя ли сделать так, чтобы при создании swf все объекты в сцене автоматически преобразовывались в растровую графику?

Comment: А что значит "вручную"? Скрипты с Imagemagick'ом кто-то поставил под строгий запрет?

Comment: даже не знаю что это, просветите пожалуйста)

Comment: www.imagemagick.org набор утилит для выполнения операций над изображениями: конвертация, преобразование, нанесение текст, слияние, сравнение. Некогда был весьма популярен у вебдевелоперов. (преобразование формата осуществляется в convert). В скриптах и/или make-файлах эти операции можно выполнять над множеством картинок.

Comment: Можно в лоб - вместо каждого векторного объекта создать битмап, после чего выполнить на него `bitmapData.draw()` того вектора, который он будет заменять. А потом оперировать именно битмапами. Ещё вариант пробежать по всем векторным объектам и выставить `cacheAsBitmap=true` просто в цикле, кодом: `for (var i:int=this.numChildren-1;i>=0;i--) this.getChildAt(i).cacheAsBitmap=true;`